# Cannot implement socketIO pod in Kotlin multiflatform

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

```
cocoapods {
    ios.deploymentTarget = "15.2"

    version = "1.0"

    summary = "This is sample Summary"
    homepage = "Home URL"

    pod("socket.IO")
}
```

While I try make grade sync I got this error. I think I have add some extraOption in pod integration but I don't have any idea.
Maybe problem is that socket.IO uses very old target version and some value type

```
Executing of 'xcodebuild -project Pods.xcodeproj -scheme socket.IO -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release' failed with code 65 and message: 


^
1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/nekbakhtzabirov/Documents/MarshalKMM/shared/build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS/Pods/socket.IO/SocketIOTransportWebsocket.m:21:
/Users/nekbakhtzabirov/Documents/MarshalKMM/shared/build/cocoapods/synthetic/IOS/Pods/socket.IO/SocketIOTransportWebsocket.h:23:9: fatal error: could not build module 'SocketRocket'
#import "SRWebSocket.h"
```